# The bracha on Hallel and interruption during the Crusades

Tags: history, blessing, nusach-ashkenaz, hallel

[The correct bracha](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21140&st=&pgnum=14&hilite=) on real Hallel (as opposed to Rosh Chodesh and the end of Pesach) is לגמור את ההלל.  The Maharam advised people to instead say לקרוא את ההלל because if you say לגמור and then miss a word, it would be a bracha levatala, and this is what Ashkenazim do.

I was listening today to R' Fendel of the Sderot hesder yeshiva describing how the sirens started in the middle of Hallel on Shemini Atzeres.  I seem to recall a similar story in a kinnah describing an interruption by Crusaders (?) in the middle of Hallel on Shavuos, and was wondering if there's any connection to the Maharam's psak.  Is there any possibility that the Maharam was making a zeicher to the story and trying to emphasize the kedusha of the martyrs' unfinished Hallel?

(With obvious parallels to soldiers who interrupted their Hallel to fight...)

Comment: You're probably thinking of https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%99_%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%9F_%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99_%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D וּבַחֹדֶשׁ הַשְּׁלִישִׁי בִּקְרִיאַת הַלֵּל לְשׁוֹרְרָה hallel on rosh chodesh sivan

Comment: See number 2 here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/80562/759 Seems maharam just had a very flexible conception of nusach habracha (there are some other examples too that don't come to mind now. also we know he wrote many piyyutim that made it to machzorim)

Comment: @DoubleAA that's a necessary condition for changing the bracha, not sufficient.  It's not like he randomly changed them for no reason at all.  I was being a little poetic and influenced by current events, a sufficient condition could just as easily be something boring like one time he heard a chazzan who wasn't careful with words.